# Windows 7 partition now renamed LVM

Tags: boot

I have a Windows 7 machine that I was trying to install Ubuntu 17.10 in a dual boot configuration. I booted the machine into Ubuntu using a USB stick and started the installation. But I was unsure of how to partition the 1 TB drive so I aborted the installation until I investigated the partitioning issue further. I might have started down a path that I should not have because....

.....On re-booting however, Windows would not work. With the Ubuntu USB, the entire hard drive is now named "unknown" and type "Linux LVM". It appears that the Windows partition is unseen to Windows.

Is there a way to salvage Windows so that I don't have to re-install it? There are several threads on a similar issue but none specific to my situation that I can find.

Comment: You didn't *rename* your Windows partition. You *reformatted* it. You now have a Data Recovery problem, not an Ubuntu problem. If there is important data you wish to salvage, then stop using the drive RIGHT NOW and start learning about data recovery. Windows, if you want it, must be reinstalled.

Comment: I would download `testdisk` and hope it can see your old partitions.